# Spaces with unique endomorphism monoids

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, semigroups-and-monoids

If $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space, let $\text{End}(X)$ denote the collection of all continuous maps $f: X\to X$. With composition, this becomes the *endomorphism monoid* $(\text{End}(X), \circ)$.

We say that the space $X$ has a *unique endomorphism monoid* if $\text{End}(X) \cong \text{End}(Y)$ as monoids, for some space $Y$, then the spaces $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic.

**Question.** Is there for every infinite cardinality $\kappa$ a space $(X,\tau)$ with unique endomorphism monoid, and $|X| = \kappa$?

Comment: My offhand guess would be 'no', but have you settled this for finite spaces?

Comment: The 1-point space is my friend :-) Then I believe the Sierpinsky space (on 2 points) has this property, that is $\mathbb{S} = (\{0,1\}, \{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{0,1\}) = (2,3)$, if we regard $2,3$ as ordinals!. From this I would proceed with induction, take $\mathbb{S}_n = (n, n+1)$ for $n\in\omega\setminus\{0\}$ (so $\mathbb{S}_1$ is the 1-point space and $\mathbb{S}_2$ is the Sierpinsky space, etc.

Comment: I don't follow. How do you know that for every finite space $Y$, if $\hom(Y, Y) \cong \hom(\mathbb{S}_n, \mathbb{S}_n)$, then $Y \cong \mathbb{S}_n$?

Comment: Right - I want to try to prove it for the standard Sierpinski space $\mathbb{S}_2$ first. Or do you see straight away a space that is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}_2$ but has the same endomorphism monoid? I will think about this and get back here

Comment: I think you're safe with $\mathbb{S}_2$, since any finite space with at least three points has at least four endomorphisms (constants and identity). But the situation for general $\mathbb{S}_n$ is less clear to me.

Comment: As a first, trivial remark, a map $f: \mathbb{S}_n \to \mathbb{S}_n$ is continuous if and only if it is order-preserving (if we order $n$ with the usual ordering $\in$ that it has as an ordinal). Then I was able to prove that if $Y$ is any topological space such that $\text{End}(Y) \cong \text{End}(\mathbb{S}_n)$, then we have $|Y| = n$. Unfortunately, the comment section here is too short to contain this argument. This has implications on the structure of $\text{End}(Y)$ and $\text{End}(\mathbb{S}_n)$ respectively. I don't know what would be a good place to post this very long comment

Comment: I wish I had more time for this. Maybe later on Thursday. (However, a short argument that $\text{End}(X) \cong \text{End}(Y)$ for finite $X, Y$ implies they have the same cardinality: the constant functions $X \to X$ are uniquely characterized as those endomorphisms $\phi$ that are left-absorbing, i.e., $\phi = \phi \circ \psi$ for every $\psi$. So $X, Y$ would have the same number of left-absorbing endos.) There might be a Schroeder-Bernstein type argument that I'm missing that would help here.

Comment: I'm also busy on Tuesday and Wednesday with other matters and will get back to this on Thursday. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: I expanded my comment to an answer. In particular, the Sierpiński spaces $\mathbb S_n$ do indeed have the property.

Comment: Thanks @EmilJeřábek! And you also answer the generalization, whether for infinite cardinals $\kappa$ we have that $S_\kappa = (\kappa, \kappa+1)$ has a unique endomorphism monoid

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\End{End}$As shown in Todd Trimble’s comment, the set of constant maps $X\to X$ is definable in $\End(X,\tau)$, as it consists of exactly the left-absorbing endomorphisms (i.e., $\phi\in\End(X,\tau)$ such that $\phi\circ\psi=\phi$ for all $\psi\in\End(X,\tau)$). Thus, an isomorphism $F\colon\End(X,\tau)\to\End(Y,\sigma)$ induces a bijection $f\colon X\to Y$ such that $F(c_x)=c_{f(x)}$ for all $x\in X$, where $c_x\colon X\to X$ is the constant-$x$ map. But then $F$ is completely determined by $f$ by
$$F(\phi)(f(x))=f(\phi(x))$$
for all $\phi\in\End(X,\tau)$: indeed, we have
$$c_{f(\phi(x))}=F(c_{\phi(x)})=F(\phi\circ c_x)=F(\phi)\circ F(c_x)=F(\phi)\circ c_{f(x)}=c_{F(\phi)(f(x))}.$$
Since we may as well assume that $X=Y$ and $f$ is the identity, it follows that:

> **Lemma 1.** $(X,\tau)$ has a unique endomorphism monoid iff it is homeomorphic to all spaces of the form $(X,\sigma)$ such that $\End(X,\tau)$ and $\End(X,\sigma)$ are literally equal (i.e., a map $X\to X$ is an endomorphism of $(X,\tau)$ iff it is an endomorphism of $(X,\sigma)$.)

This implies

> **Proposition 2.** If $(X,\le)$ is a total order which is isomorphic to its opposite order, then the [Alexandrov space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology) $(X,\tau)$ of upper sets of $(X,\le)$ has a unique endomorphism monoid. In particular, there exist such spaces of arbitrary cardinality.

Indeed, let $\sigma$ be a topology on $X$ such that $\End(X,\sigma)$ consists of the order-preserving maps. We may assume $|X|\ge2$. Then $\sigma$ cannot be indiscrete, hence we can fix $V\in\sigma$ and $a$ and $b$ such that $a\notin V$, $b\in V$. Assume first $a<b$. Then $\tau\subseteq\sigma$: consider an upper set $U\in\tau$. The map
$$\phi_{a,b,U}(x)=\begin{cases}b&x\in U,\\a&x\notin U\end{cases}$$
is order-preserving, hence $\phi_{a,b,U}\in\End(X,\sigma)$, and $\phi_{a,b,U}^{-1}[V]=U$, thus $U\in\sigma$. In fact, $\sigma=\tau$: if we assume for contradiction that $W\in\sigma$ is not an upper set, then the argument above shows that $\sigma$ also includes all lower sets, thus for any upper set $U$, $\phi_{b,a,U}\in\End(X,\sigma)$, but $\phi_{b,a,U}$ is not order-preserving if $U\notin\{\varnothing,X\}$.

Dually, if $a>b$, we obtain that $\sigma$ consists of all lower subsets of $X$, hence it is the Alexandrov topology corresponding to the opposite of $\le$, but this is homeomorphic to $(X,\tau)$ by our assumption on $\le$.

---

One can generalize the argument to a complete characterization for Alexandrov spaces. (Note that in particular, all finite spaces are Alexandrov.)  First, a lemma. If $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space, let $x\le_\tau y$ denote the specialization preorder $x\in\overline{\{y\}}$, and $x\sim_\tau y$ the indistinguishability equivalence $x\le_\tau y\land y\le_\tau x$.

> **Lemma 3.** If $\End(X,\tau)=\End(X,\sigma)$, then ${\sim_\tau}={\sim_\sigma}$ unless one space is discrete and the other indiscrete.

**Proof:** If, say, $a\sim_\tau b$ but $a\nsim_\sigma b$, then all mappings $X\to\{a,b\}$ are in $\End(X,\tau)$, hence in $\End(X,\sigma)$, hence $(X,\sigma)$ is discrete, hence all mappings $X\to X$ are in $\End(X,\tau)$, hence $(X,\tau)$ is indiscrete lest $a\nsim_\tau b$. QED

> **Proposition 4.** If $(X,\tau)$ is an Alexandrov space, then $\End(X,\tau)\simeq\End(Y,\sigma)$ if and only if
>
> - $(Y,\sigma)$ is homeomorphic to $(X,\tau)$, or
> - $(Y,\sigma)$ is homeomorphic to the opposite of $(X,\tau)$ (i.e., the Alexandrov space corresponding to $\ge_\tau$), or
> - the two spaces are the discrete and indiscrete topologies on sets of the same cardinality.
>
> Consequently, $(X,\tau)$ has a unique endomorphism monoid iff $(X,\le_\tau)\simeq(X,\ge_\tau)$, and $\tau$ is neither discrete nor indiscrete unless $|X|\le1$.

**Proof:** The right-to-left implication is clear. For the left-to-right implication, we may assume $X=Y$ and $\End(X,\tau)=\End(X,\sigma)$ as above.

Assume first that $\le_\tau$ is an equivalence (i.e., ${\le_\tau}={\sim_\tau}$). By Lemma 3, we may assume that ${\sim_\tau}={\sim_\sigma}$ and $\tau$ is not indiscrete. (If $\tau$ is indiscrete, then either $\sigma$ is discrete and we are done, or ${\sim}_\sigma={\sim}_\tau$, hence $\sigma$ is indiscrete, i.e., $\sigma=\tau$, and we are also done.) Since $\tau$ is the finest topology with indistinguishability relation $\sim_\tau$, this implies $\sigma\subseteq\tau$; on the other hand, if we fix $a\nsim_\tau b$, and w.l.o.g. $a\lnsim_\sigma b$, then $\phi_{a,b,U}$ is in $\End(X,\sigma)$ for all $U\in\tau$, hence $U\in\sigma$, i.e., $\sigma=\tau$.

If $\le_\tau$ is not an equivalence, let us fix $a\lnsim_\tau b$. This also implies we can fix $V\in\tau$ whose complement is not in $\tau$. Then $\phi_{a,b,V}\in\End(X,\tau)$ and $\phi_{b,a,V}\notin\End(X,\tau)$, hence $a\lnsim_\sigma b$ or $b\lnsim_\sigma a$. W.lo.g., we assume the former (the other choice leads to the opposite order). Then for each $U\in\tau$, $\phi_{a,b,U}\in\End(X,\tau)$ implies $U\in\sigma$, i.e., $\tau\subseteq\sigma$. Since $\tau$ is the finest topology with specialization preorder $\le_\tau$, if $\tau\subsetneq\sigma$, then (in view of ${\sim_\tau}={\sim_\sigma}$) there are $x,y$ such that $x\lnsim_\tau y$ and $x\nleq_\sigma y\nleq_\sigma x$. But as above, this contradicts $\phi_{x,y,V}\notin\End(X,\sigma)$ for suitable $V\in\tau$. Thus, $\tau=\sigma$. QED

---

The characterization can be easily extended to all non-$R_0$ spaces. Recall that $(X,\tau)$ is $R_0$ if $\le_\tau$ is symmetric (i.e., ${\le_\tau}={\sim_\tau}$).

> **Proposition 5.** If $(X,\tau)$ is a non-Alexandrov non-$R_0$ space, then $(X,\tau)$ has a unique endomorphism monoid.

**Proof:** Assume that $\End(X,\tau)=\End(X,\sigma)$. Let us fix $a\lnsim_\tau b$. There exists $V\in\tau$ whose complement is not in $\tau$ (e.g., any open set separating $b$ from $a$); then $\phi_{a,b,V}\in\End(X,\tau)$ and $\phi_{b,a,V}\notin\End(X,\tau)$, hence (1) $a\lnsim_\sigma b$ or (2) $b\lnsim_\sigma a$. (In particular, $(X,\sigma)$ is not $R_0$.) If (1) holds, then for every $U\in\tau$, $\phi_{a,b,U}\in\End(X,\tau)$ implies $U=\phi_{a,b,U}^{-1}[b]\in\sigma$, i.e., $\tau\subseteq\sigma$. If (2) holds, then the same argument gives $\{X\smallsetminus U:U\in\tau\}\subseteq\sigma$.

Since $(X,\sigma)$ is not $R_0$ either, a symmetric argument implies that (1') $\sigma\subseteq\tau$, or (2') $\{X\smallsetminus U:U\in\sigma\}\subseteq\tau$. It is impossible that (1) and (2') hold together: this would imply that $\tau$ is closed under complement, whence it is $R_0$. Likewise, (2) and (1') are incompatible. Thus, the only two possibilities are that either (1) and (2) hold, in which case $\tau=\sigma$, or (1') and (2') hold, in which case $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are mutually opposite Alexandrov spaces. QED

Notice that $(X,\tau)$ is $R_0$ iff the Kolmogorov quotient $X/{\sim_\tau}$ is $T_1$. It is easy to see that:

> **Lemma 6.** If $(X,\tau)$ and $(X,\sigma)$ are spaces such that ${\sim_\tau}={\sim_\sigma}$, then $\End(X,\tau)=\End(X,\sigma)$ iff $\End((X,\tau)/{\sim_\tau})=\End((X,\sigma)/{\sim_\sigma})$.

In view of Lemma 3, this gives a reduction of the remaining classification to $T_1$ spaces. Observe that an $R_0$ space $(X,\tau)$ is Alexandrov iff $(X,\tau)/{\sim_\tau}$ is discrete.

> **Corollary 7.** If $(X,\tau)$ is an $R_0$ non-Alexandrov space, then $(X,\tau)$ has a unique mononorphism monoid iff the $T_1$ space $(X,\tau)/{\sim_\tau}$ has a unique monomorphism monoid.

Comment: Brilliant, Emil, thanks a lot!

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: Fullbright (+1) !

Answer (score 2):

While the OP question ultimately is specific (as it should), it really offers an entire topic:

**TOPIC**:  What are topological spaces
$\ (X\ T)\ $ which are topologically uniquely characterized by monoid $\ \text{End}(X\ T)\,?$

In other words, given an abstract monoid $\ M,\ $ can
we recover topological space $\ (X\ T)\ $ **uniquely** (if at all) so that $\ M\ $ and $\ \text{End}(X\ T)\ $ are isomorphic (as abstract algebraic monoids).

In this *answer*, let me provide some tools.

Let $\ \mathbf M:=(M\ \circ\ J)\ $ be an arbitrary monoid.  Let
$$ C\ :=\ \{c\in M:\ \forall_{f\in M}\ c\circ f=c\} $$

If $\ \mathbf M\ $ were isomorphic to $\ \text{End}(X\ T)\ $
then $\ C\ $ and $\ X\ $ would be in a canonical 1-1 correspondence as mentioned by @YCor in a comment to Dominic's 
[real-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356049/what-spaces-x-do-have-textendx-cong-textend-mathbbr/356165#356165). This is the basic starting tool.

Next, let's discuss the next tool, the idempotents
$\ i\in\mathcal I\subseteq M,\ $ where

$$ \mathcal I\ :=\ \{i\in M:\ i\circ i=i\} $$

For instance, the unit $\ J\in M\ $ and constants
$\ c\in C\ $ are all idempotents.

**Definition**
$$ \forall_{i\ j\,\in\mathcal I}\quad
    (\,i\subseteq j\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\
      j\circ i=i\,) $$

It follows that:

- $\ \forall_{i\in\mathcal I}\quad i\subseteq i;$
- $\ \forall_{i\ j\ k\in\mathcal I}\quad(
      (i\subseteq j\ \text{and}\ j\subseteq k)\ \Rightarrow
        i\subseteq k) $
- $\ \forall_{i\in\mathcal I}\,
        \forall_{j\in C}\quad
         (\ i\subseteq j\ \Rightarrow\ j=i\ ) $

Topological idempotents $\ i:X\to X\ $ are closely related to Karol Borsuk's retractions; such idempotent
$\ i\ $ retract $\ X\ $ retracts $\ X\ $ onto
$\ i(X)\subseteq X. $

By Bourbaki theorem, $\ (X\ T)\ $ is Hausdorff
$\ \Leftrightarrow\ \Delta_X:=\{(x\ x):x\in X\ $ is closed in $\ X\times X.$ It follows that for Hausdorff spaces the said retract $\ i(X)\ $ is closed in $\ X.\ $ **Indeed,**
$$ i(X)\ :=\ \{x:\ i(x)=x\}\ =
   \ (i\triangle \text{Id}_X)^{-1}(\Delta_X) $$
for diagonal product function
$\ i\triangle \text{Id}_X : X\to X\times X.$

***Great!.*** (This is obviously useful for Hausdorff spaces).

Let $\ \pi:\mathcal I\to 2^C\ $ be defined by

$$ \forall_{i\in\mathcal I}\quad \pi(i)\ :=
         \ \{c\in C:\ i\circ c = c\} $$

This is how idempotents of $\ \mathbf M\ $ point to the respective subsets of $\ X;\ $ or to closed subsets in the Hausdorff case -- I mean pointing to $\ \pi(i).$

**Theorem**

- $\ \forall_{i\ j\in\mathcal I}\quad(\,i\subseteq j
      \ \Rightarrow \pi(i)\subseteq\pi(j)\, ) $
- $\ \forall_{i\ j\in\mathcal I}\quad(\,(i\subseteq j
        \ \text{and}\ j\subseteq i)
      \ \Rightarrow\ \pi(i)=\pi(j)\, ) $
- $\ \forall_{i\in\mathcal I}\quad (\, i\in C
      \ \Leftrightarrow\ \pi(i)=\{i\} $

Another tool, the uc-*morphisms* and nuc-*morphims*, was mentioned in my answer to [Dominic's-real-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356049/what-spaces-x-do-have-textendx-cong-textend-mathbbr/356165#356165). In topological language, if $\ i\ $ is a topological idempotent then $\ I(X)\ $ has or has not fpp when $\ i\ $ is an uc-morphism or nuc-morphism respectively.

These tools may serve as a starting point to a discussion of specific topological spaces or their classes.

Comment: I enjoyed this answer very much! Thank you

Comment: This is really cool. Are there any paper's on this topic? I'm currently looking into cannonical topologies on monoids and the quetion "What are topological spaces  (X T) 
 which are topologically uniquely characterized by monoid  End(X T)?" came up natrually. Google then brought me here :)

Answer (score 1):

**NOTATION**

$$ S_X\ :=\ \{\emptyset\ X\} $$
$$ D_X\ :=\ 2^X\ =\ \{A:\ A\subseteq X\} $$

Given an arbitrary set $\ X,\ $ topology $\ S_X\ $ is the smallest (the weakest) topology in $\ X;\ $ and the discrete topology $\ D_X\ $ is the largest (the strongest) topology in $\ X.$

### --------------------

Here is a logically initial modest positive result:

**Theorem**   Let set $\ X\ $ be finite. Then for every non-discrete topological space $\ (Y\ T)\ $ (i.e. $\ T\ne D_Y),\ $ if monoids $\ \text{End}(X\ S_X)\ $ and
$\ \text{End}(Y\ T)\ $ are isomorphic then topological spaces $\ (X\ S_X)\,$ and $\,(Y\ T)\ $ are homeomorphic, i.e. $\,\ |Y|=|X|\ $ and $\ T=S_Y.$

**Proof**   If two monoids are isomorphic than they have the same number (cardinality) of constants (of the left-absorbing elements). Furthermore, the number of points of an arbitrary topological space is equal to the number the constants of its monoid of continuous self-maps.

Let's assume that monoids $\ \text{End}(X\ S_X)\ $ and
$\ \text{End}(Y\ T)\ $ are isomorphic. Then

$$ |X|\ =\ |Y| $$

Also,
$$ |\text{End}(X\ S_X)|\ =\ |\text{End}(Y\ T)|\ $$
hence

$$ |\text{End}(Y\ T)|\ =\ |\text{End}(X\ S_X)|
                \ =\ |X^X| $$
so that
$$ |\text{End}(Y\ T)|\ =\ |Y^Y| $$

This means that $\ T=S_Y\ $ or $\ T=D_Y\ $ hence,
by theorem's assumption, $\ T=S_Y\ $ --
**otherwise** $\ T\ $ would be not discrete nor the
smallest, i.e. there exists $\ G\ \in\ T\setminus S_Y\ $ and non-isolated $\ p\in Y\ $ (i.e. such that
$\ \{p\}\not\in T)$. Then consider $\ f:Y\to Y\ $ such that $ f(p)\in G\ $ and
$\ f(Y\setminus\{p\})\subseteq Y\setminus G.\ $ Such
$\ f\ $ is not continuous in $\ (Y\ T),\ $ hence
$$ |\text{End}(Y\ T)|\ <\ |Y^Y| $$

-- a contradiction.   **End of PROOF**

### ----------------

**Remark** For every set $\ X,\ $ monoids

$$ \text{End}(X\ S_X)\quad \text{and}\quad
        \text{End}(X\ D_X)\ $$

are isomorphic while the respective topological spaces $\ (X\ S_X)\ $ and $\ (X\ D_X)\ $ are not homeomorphic whenever $\ |X|>1.$